# ElectronJS BrowserWindow FOUC

Tags: javascript, css, electron

When I create a new BrowserWindow and use loadURL to use an html file inside renderer, I can see a flash of unstyled content for half a second, before the css is loaded I guess.

```
window.loadURL('file://' + resolve(__dirname, '..', 'static', 'hello-world', 'index.html')
```

in index.js

```
import './index.css'
```

Comment: What do you see if you replace your `loadURL` call with `window.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)` and is your css import line at the top of your html file?

Comment: I have to use path resolve because the build has that path, but makes no difference, and yes, the css is on top. I'm wondering if this is the "official" way of creating a new BrowserWindow.

Comment: @JorgeOrtega Do you want to show splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the window as hidden, and once the content has been loaded (did-finish-load event) you'll show it. This prevents the flashing.

**Code for main process**

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  show: false, // loads the window without showing it
  webPreferences: {
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
})

win.loadFile('index.html')


win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function () {
  win.show()  // show the window now since everything is ready
})
```